# Drag and Drop between iFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to drag a picture from Picker.html, which is one of the Google APIs, into another iFrame containing a chat app. So, the picture is uploaded into chat and it would be able to be sent.
I know that browser security measures prevent this and I have already tried this solution [Drag-Drop elements between parent frame and child iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692448/drag-drop-elements-between-parent-frame-and-child-iframe). 
However I would like to know if there is a different solution using only HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery. Thank you very much!

Comment: if there's a link around the image, dropping it should be able to reveal the url of the link.